# why is desktop.ini file created?

Tags: python, tkinter, visual-studio-code

I made a program using tkinter (GUI module). basically it is a banking system that stores data in text files. I found that a desktop.ini file was created in that folder. why so? Is it harmful if I delete the file?

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll,27
[ViewState]
Mode=
Vid=
FolderType=Generic
```

this is what is there in that file.

Comment: Its happening when you using custom folder icon on project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a windows config file and is not harmful or a vulnerability

Comment: ok. will I face issues if I delete it? also what is the __pycahche __ file ?

Comment: no, you won't, it may be recreated automaticly again __pycache__ is a directory that contains bytecode cache files that are automatically generated by python it is safe to delete it too but I would say let it be there

Comment: if your question was answered you can mark my answer as answered by clicking ✓

Answer (score 2):

According to https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/there-are-these-random-desktopini-files-appearing/5bb923f5-6b06-4e07-a79e-a16c8bfc844a

> You should not delete them.
> A Desktop.ini file is a file that determines the way a folder is displayed by Windows. These files can be found in any folder, anywhere on your computer, as long as that folder has a custom appearance set for it. Desktop.ini files control things like the icon used for that folder and its localized name.
> Deleting them will always regenerate them anyway. If you don't want to see them, turn off show hidden files and folders in File Explorer > View tab > uncheck hidden files.